# How does this unique() function work

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

As I was looking at a `unique()` function I found
which takes an array as argument and returns a new array which contains the unique elements of this array (which means no duplicated items). However I cannot understand the logic of this function. Can somebody explain it to me?

Here is the function:

```
function unique ( array ) {
    return array.filter(function(a){
        return !this[a] ? this[a] = true : false;
    }, {});
}
```

I can't really understand the whole code especially the `!this[a] ? this[a] = true : false;` and the new object (`{}`) that is passed as the second argument to `filter`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start with the [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

> The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass
>   the test implemented by the provided function.

The `a` is the random number of the array to which you apply the filter. The whole essence is in the following statement:

```
return !this[a] ? this[a] = true : false;
```

If the `this[a]` is true, `a` has been already processed once and it has been added to this as one of its properties. Otherwise, `this[a]` is false. So taking its negation result in true and the current `a` should be returned. Furthermore `this[a]` would be set to true and then we proceed to the next `a`.

The following snippet will help you grasp what `filter` does:

```js
var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5];
var filteredNumbers = numbers.filter(function(number){
    console.log(number);
    return number > 2;
});
console.log(filteredNumbers);
```

And the following snippet will show you in action what happens in `unique` function:

```js
function unique ( array ) {
  return array.filter(function(a){
    console.log(this);
    return !this[a] ? this[a] = true : false;
  }, {});
}

var array = [1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5,5,6];

console.log(unique(array));
```

> I understand the basic logic of filter but what i dont is the {}
>   passed as a 2nd argument and how each value is added to a new array
>   with !this[a]

The second argument is an *optional* value that you can pass to the `filter` method and it can be used as the `this`, when your callback would be executed (check the link I mentioned at the beginning about `filter`). You pass there an empty object. When you use the keyword `this` inside your callback, your refer this object. This is why the first time that code gets in this method returns `{}`. Check the first line of the output of the second snippet.

I will explain the second part of your question based on the second snippet. The first time you get in you have an empty object (I refer to this) and the first number processed is 1. So this[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) would be undefined. So `!this[1]` would be true. Hence the first part after the `?` is executed which is an assignment

```
this[1] = true.
```

Now `this` acquired its first key, 1, with value `true`. Furthermore, 1 would be returned from filter. The same happens with 2 and 3. When we arrive at 1 the

```
!this[1]
```

is false, since `this[1]` is true. So false is returned and the 1 now would not be added to the array that would be returned after all elements of array have been processed.

Comment: No it is the random item of your array.

Comment: @ManosKounelakis please have a look at the snippet I added, in order to see it in action.

Comment: I understand the basic logic of filter but what i dont is the ```{}``` passed as a 2nd argument and how each value is added to a new array with ```!this[a]```

Comment: *Otherwise, `this[a]` is false.* No, otherwise, `this[a]` is undefined.

Comment: Does filter also convert {"1": true, "2": true,"3": true, "4": true, "5": true,"6": true} to [1,2,3,4,5,6] ?

Comment: @SandeepSharma no it does not

Answer (score 2):

Basically, `.filter` would call the `callBack` function by supplying the individual values of the iterating array. If the `callBack` returns a value that resolves to `true` then that value will be collected, else that particular value will be ignored.

Here the second argument of `filter` has been used. That second argument will be used as a context(`this`) while calling the `callBack` internally. So here in your code, the passed object will be added with the array's value as property for each iteration. And in the consecutive iterations, the code will check the current value is available as a `property` in the initially passed object. If available then that ternary operator would return `false`, otherwise `true`.

Hence the unique values will be returned from the filter function.

Answer (score 0):

[Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) will only grab elements of the array when the function passed return [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy).

For each element of the array it is doing

```
return !this[a] // if value is not yet on this
  ? this[a] = true  // add value to this and return true (grab element)
  : false;  // value was already cached, so return false (don't grab)
```

So it will only return 1 of each

Comment: this[a] = true  // how is this adding value and returning true?

Comment: When you assign a value to a variable it returns the value you are assigning. If you type `a = 1` on the console you will see `1`. The exception on this is when you declare a var `var a = 1` will return undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers have explained basically how this works. But a couple of points:

First, instead of `return !this[a] ? this[a] = true : false;`, it would be more concise to write

```
!this[a] && (this[a] = true)
```

Second, this code has the flaw that it only works on elements which can serve as keys into an object--basically strings or numbers. That is why using `Set` is better:

```
Array.from(new Set(array))
```

The above will work on any primitive **or** object.

Third, this approach does not work properly with strings and numbers. If the number `1` is present, it will filter out the string `"1"`.

```js
const uniq = a => a.filter(x => !this[x] && (this[x] = true), {});
console.log(uniq([1, '1']));
```

The reason is that object keys are string-valued.

Finally, IMHO this code is a bit too tricky for its own good. Most developers, even experienced ones, would stop and scratch their heads for a minute before figuring it out. Less experienced developers would have to consult the documentation for the `thisArg` parameter to `Array#filter` before being able to understand it. The ternary operator with the assignment inside is also a bit cryptic. I'd go ahead and write it out as

```
if (this[x]) return false;
this[x] = true;
return true;
```